# expiration date of credit card in php

Tags: php, validation

This is my code, I have tried almost everything on google regarding the validation of the expired date, none of it worked. is there any/or did you know hoe to code the expired date?

```
if(isset($_POST['SEND']))
{
    $cem = $_POST['card-exp-month'];
    $cn4 = $_POST['card-no-4'];
    $cey = $_POST['card-exp-year'];
    $cvv = $_POST['cvv'];
    $tp = $_POST['totalprice'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 hours'));

    include "phpcreditcard.php";

    if ($t)
    {
        $mySql ="INSERT INTO orderm VALUES ('','$member_ID','$date','$member_address','$tp', '$t', '$cn4')";
        $myQry= mysql_query($mySql, $DB)or die("query fail".mysql_error());
    }
```

This is the code in the phpcredicard:

```
function checkExpDate($cem,$cey) 

{

$expTs = mktime(0, 0, 0, $cem + 1, 1, $cey);
$curTs = time();
$maxTs = $curTs + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);
if ($expTs > $curTs && $expTs < $maxTs) {
    return true;
} else {
    return 0;           
}
```

}

This is my form

```
        <label class="control-label">Card Expiry Date</label>
        <div class="controls">
         <td> <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span5">
              <select  name="card-exp-month" class="input-block-level">
                <option value="01">January</option>
                <option value="02">February</option>
                <option value="03">March</option>
                <option value="04">April</option>
                <option value="05">May</option>
                <option value="06">June</option>
                <option value="07">July</option>
                <option value="08">August</option>
                <option value="09">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <select name="card-exp-year" class="input-block-level">
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
              </select>
```

Comment: What is not working? How isn't it working? What error messages do you get? What result do you expect to get? What, exactly, is inside the "phpcreditcard.php" file?

Comment: i want the expired date to be valid, how do i do that>

Comment: It looks like your checkExpDate() function doesn't have a closing brace '}'

Answer (score 0):

If the code you've posted above is the complete code from the file, then the problem is that you have an open code block. A mismatched pair of curly braces, in other words.

Had you been indenting your code properly, which I did with your original post, then it would have been easy to spot this. Which is one of the (many) reasons why it's so important to ensure a consistent and sane coding style.

Also, for future reference: Please post the entire error message you get. Just make sure that you've actually tried to understand it first, as the more effort you put into a question the more help you will receive.

Comment: is the function on phpcreditcard correct? is my coding above correct? i add the closing bracket, it still error,

Comment: I quote: "Please post the entire error message you get"

Comment: there is no error. but it doesnt work as nothing happen, the validation is not working, even i chose "january" "2016"